# UnrealIRCD - Starting problem

Tags: centos, irc

I have wget unrealircd and unzipped it, after ./config and make. I cannot start the unrealircd.

I get errors such as:

Starting UnrealIRCd
./unreal: line 10: /root/Unreal3.2/src/unreal/ircd: is a directory
Possible error encountered (IRCd seemingly not started)

I am using unrealircd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `Config` again and specify the full path to the binary including the name of the binary file not just the path to the directory containing the binary when asked this

```
What is the path to the ircd binary including the name of the binary?
[/some/path/to/the/ircd] ->
```

Comment: @lain sorry I corrected the path "./unreal: line 10: /root/Unreal3.2/src/unreal/ircd: is a directory Possible error encountered (IRCd seemingly not started)" it still has the same problems. Is it because of the unreal config file?

Comment: Find where your ircd binary is then have a look at the unreal script line 10 it should point to the unreal ircd binary e.g. /home/iain/unreal/Unreal3.2/src/ircd.

Comment: @lain there is nothing in the directory...

Comment: Did your make complete cleanly ?

Comment: Yes, what is this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1> You shouldn't run IRC as root but a normal user because there is no reason to run IRC with elevated privileges. It's more secure to keep processes off the root account unless really needed. IRC really doesn't need it.
2> You can try: **./Config -nocache** and let the path questions be default as they are. Then **make**.

The default paths will be something like:

What directory are all the server configuration files in?
[/home/user/Unreal3.2] ->

What is the path to the ircd binary including the name of the binary?
[/home/user/Unreal3.2/src/ircd] ->

Both these paths are perfectly acceptable and work out of the box.